# How to make variable return different values on access?

Tags: kotlin

I have a homework question "Implement a val property that returns a different value on each access"

I can imagine how I can return different values with function, but not with variable. Is there some "linux-like" link to this function in Kotlin I should make?

Comment: make it of generic return type, or use Kotlin Any class

Comment: Use a custom getter: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple example. I recommend reading [Kotlin's documentation on getters and setters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters).

```
class CustomGetter {
    private var underlyingField: Int = 0

    private var alwaysHigher: Int = this.underlyingField
    get() {
        this.underlyingField++
        field = underlyingField
        return field
    }
}
```